# Asp.Net Core not showing developer exception page even though env.IsDevelopment is true

Tags: asp.net-core, exception

My startup code has the following:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseBrowserLink();
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
```

A breakpoint confirms that the env.IsDevelopment route is executed.

Yet when I hit an exception, the /Home/Error Action is executed (confirmed by a breakpoint in that Action method's code), and the corresponding view is returned:
[image: Not the Developer Exception Page]

How can it be telling me to swap to the development environment even though the breakpoint in my Startup confirms I am already in the development environment?

**EDIT**

Ok nevermind...the problem seems to be deeper down in IdentityServer4's code. That's the source of the exception, and somehow it ends up ignoring the DeveloperExceptionPage setting. Other exceptions thrown elsewhere in my own code correctly return the DeveloperExceptionPage

Comment: If you comment out these lines, will you get `/Home/Error` Action executed? I suggest you check whether you call `Return View("/Home/Error")` directly. Try to share us the complete `Startup`.

Comment: Ok nevermind...the problem seems to be deeper down in IdentityServer4's code.  That's the source of the exception, and somehow it ends up ignoring the DeveloperExceptionPage setting.  Other exceptions thrown elsewhere in my own code correctly return the DeveloperExceptionPage.

Comment: @ShawndeWet I have exactly the same problem now (with IdentityServer4). Did you solve the issue back then?

Comment: @Episodex Nope, never did get to the bottom of WHY IDS4 does this, but I worked around it by logging exceptions, and then did what I had to in order to fix the situation that was causing IDS4 to throw an exception in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but I will post our solution for a related usecase where errors happening inside IdentityServer bypassed the exceptionhandling in Startup. This was an issue for us, since we wanted to show the correlation ID corresponding to the error on the errorpage.

We ended up with a middleware that checks if there's a redirect to the errorpage, and if so, we append the correlation ID to the query parameters.

The middleware we ended up with looks like this:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// This middleware is necessary to handle exceptions that are handled internally
/// by IdentityServer, since IdentityServer uses their own error page redirection,
/// instead of using the exceptionhandling specified in Startup.
/// 
/// If this middleware is omitted, the CorrelationId will not be transfered correctly
/// to the error page.
/// </summary>
public class IdSrvCorrelationIdTransferMiddleware
{
    public static string QueryParamKey = "correlationId";

    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<IdSrvCorrelationIdTransferMiddleware> _logger;
    private readonly ILoggingDataProvider _loggingDataProvider;

    public IdSrvCorrelationIdTransferMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate next, 
        ILogger<IdSrvCorrelationIdTransferMiddleware> logger, 
        ILoggingDataProvider loggingDataProvider)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
        _loggingDataProvider = loggingDataProvider;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        await _next.Invoke(context);

        /* If response is a redirect, and the destination is the error page, 
         * we must manually set CorrelationID. Since it's a redirect, we cannot
         * use headers to transfer CorrelationID, and instead we use query params.
         */
        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 302)
        {
            var location = context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().Location;

            if (location.IsAbsoluteUri && location.AbsolutePath == "/Home/Error".ToLower())
            {
                var correlationId = _loggingDataProvider.GetCorrelationId();

                if (correlationId.HasValue)
                {
                    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(location);
                    var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
                    query[QueryParamKey] = correlationId.Value.ToString("D");
                    uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
                    context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = uriBuilder.ToString();
                }

                _logger.LogInformation($"Redirecting user to {context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().Location}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: ILoggingDataProvider is an internal object where we store the Correlation ID.

And then we read it on the error page:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Shows the error page
/// </summary>
public async Task<IActionResult> Error()
{
    var vm = new ErrorViewModel
    {
        CorrelationId = GetCorrelationId()
    };

    return View("Error", vm);
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the correlation ID from query parameter if available, otherwise get from logging data provider
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private Guid? GetCorrelationId()
{
    if (HttpContext.Request.Query.ContainsKey(IdSrvCorrelationIdTransferMiddleware.QueryParamKey))
    {
        if (Guid.TryParse(HttpContext.Request.Query[IdSrvCorrelationIdTransferMiddleware.QueryParamKey], out Guid correlationId))
        {
            return correlationId;
        }
    }

    return _loggingDataProvider.GetCorrelationId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting UseDeveloperExceptionPage() in front of any middleware else ?

According to the middleware pipeline model , the DeveloperExceptionPage middleware must be registered first to catch exceptions .

Comment: Yes, that code snippet in my question is the first statement in the `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)` method of the Startup class.

Comment: That's really strange .  Hmm... Could you provide some more detailed information or source code if possible ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Precedence of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT < Appsettings.Json
2. first UseDeveloperExceptionPage should be registered to middleware pipeline and it displays the developer friendly error information page for any expception(s) are thrown. Please make sure that there is an being raised for the page you are expecting for.
   e.g. if you request any certain page, add "  throw new Exception("Error!");" to perticular MVC controller and then see the page.
   HTH